# Change the view prefix in pyramid traversal from "@@" to "+"

Tags: python, repoze.bfg, pyramid

I am looking at moving a web app from [pylons](http://pylonshq.com/) to [pyramid](http://docs.pylonshq.com/pyramid/dev/) (formally repoze.bfg) because traversal will fit my app much better than url dispatch.

Currently, when I have a obj with a number of views, I have the view names prefixed with a '+' in the url. e.g.:

```
/path/to/obj/   (default view)
/path/to/obj/+custom_view1
/path/to/obj/+custom_view2
/path/to/obj/+edit
/path/to/obj/+delete
/path/to/obj/sub_obj/
```

Pyramid has a feature to handle this is a nice way, but it uses the prefix "@@". Is there a way to change this to "+" so that I can keep my urls the same (you know what they say about cool urls,) and use this feature.

Comment: This should be tagged 'pyramid', but it's new, and I don't have enough rep.

Comment: + is usually used for forms that create new objects/items, so I'd recomend against that as it can be confusing. That said @@ (two googly eyes, that view, see? haha) might not be the prettiest either, but I don't know how to change it.
Btw, do you need to use @@ in Pyramid? In Zope you only need @@ if there is a name-clash with a subobject.

Comment: If you want the +, why not simply make it part of the view's name? `config.add_view(name='+edit')`?

Comment: As Lennart says, if you are content not to have any sub-objects named the same as a view ('custom_view1', ...), then the view prefix is not necessary.

Comment: The reason why I always want to have the view prefix (ant not just add the "+" to the view name), is that I can get the traversal to avoid a call to  context.__getitem__ (which the case of my app will include a db query.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no, you can change view prefix from "@@" but the new prefix should also be 2-symbold length, see [sources](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/traversal.py#L619) for traverser.

Subclassing `ResourceTreeTraverser` and then registering it instead of the default one should do the trick:

```
from pyramid.traversal import ResourceTreeTraverser as BaseResourceTreeTraverser

class ResourceTreeTraverser(BaseResourceTreeTraverser):
    VIEW_SELECTOR = "++"

from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.interfaces import ITraverser
from zope.interface import Interface

config = Configurator()
config.registry.registerAdapter(ResourceTreeTraverser, (Interface,), ITraverser)
```

Personally, I think VIEW_SELECTOR should be refactored to allow any length view prefixes.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that code, but could not figgure out how it register a custom ITraverser.

I've submitted a pull request to allow for a view selector any length. https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/pull/99